# get the host by address returning no host found in C

Tags: c, algorithm, network-programming, host

What am I doing wrong, when I pass an IP address, or any IP, it always fails in the no host found block. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    struct in_addr ip;
    inet_aton(argv[1], &ip);
    he= gethostbyaddr((const void *)&ip,len,AF_INET);
    printf("%s \n", he->h_name);
```

Comment: `gethostbyaddr` needs `in_addr` struct, not a character string.

Comment: @Anycorn I do have an in_addr structure look at the first parameter of gethostbyaddr, ip is of type in_Addr

Comment: i see this `char *ip = argv[1];`

Comment: @Anycorn if you mean get rid of the void casting, I did, still no results

Comment: You have ip declared as in_addr and then re-declared as `char*`.  this code shouldn't even compile.  are you missing parens somewhere?

Comment: @Anycorn I deleted that line of code still no results, that line was accidently included.

Comment: I think that `len` should be `sizeof(in_addr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `gethostbyaddr()` is the length of the passed *binary*
address, so `len` should be `sizeof(in_addr)`.

Remark: You should consider to use `getnameinfo()` instead, which is "more modern" and can handle both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.